# Suggestion for retrieving translations for multiple language

Tags: picklist, translation, translation-workbench, language

I have a multi-language org and very basic requirement: When a user click a button/action, value of a picklist will be sent to external system, since multiple language used, translation for other language should be sent too.

I am aware that translations done via workbench depends on user and not possible to retrieve, so currently my options:

1- Since I have 4 languages and limited picklist value to support, create new fields and maintain translations manually/hardcoded via apex for every picklist value. Con is this makes syncing translation workbench and apex an extra work, also it is hardcoded, which always a bad idea.

2- Update user and query value then update original language back, which I would prefer to avoid, I didn't try it, but I can already sense similar errors to mixed DML.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you just need values in current user's language  who submitted action , you can use toLabel()  function of soql.   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm

Comment: I wish it was like that but as I mentioned, whole purpose of this topic, external system needs all translated version of one picklist value selected by user.

Comment: Translations are stored as [metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm).  You'll have to use the open-source [metadata wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) or use REST API callouts to your own instance to get the complete set of translated values.